# Isomorphism of associated graded vector spaces implies an isomorphism of vector spaces

Tags: homological-algebra, vector-space-isomorphism, graded-modules

Let $R$ be a commutative ring and $M$ be a module with decreasing filtration $M=F_0M\supset F_1M\supset\dots$. Assume that $N$ is a $\mathbb Z$-graded $R$-module such that there is an isomorphism of graded $R$-modules

$$Gr_{\bullet}(M)\cong N,~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~(1)$$

where $Gr_{\bullet}$ denotes the associated graded module. Does $(1)$ imply an isomorphism of $R$-modules $M\cong N$? I am actually interested in the case when $R$ is a field. Then, I think, the statement is valid but I would appreciate very much an idea of a proof and a more general context if possible.

Comment: you mean in your isomorphism N with the grading ignored? if so, then yes as the forgetful functor is a functor (so it preserves isos) and the forgetful functor applied to the associated grading should (if your definition of Gr is senseful) be the identity.The other way around is heavily wrong though.

Comment: I am asking if the isomorphism of graded $R$-modules $(1)$ imply an isomorphism of (ungraded) $R$-modules $M\cong N$. In the latter isomorphism, I ignore the grading on $N$. Also, this questions is sufficiently non-trivial over a commutative ring $R$. Would you like to formulate an answer. I will gladly accept it.

Comment: well, if you can compute that the ungraded R module associated to the graded R module $\mathrm{Gr}M$ is isomorphic to $M$ you are done as that means that $\mathrm{Forget}\mathrm{Gr}M \cong M$ and so $M\cong \mathrm{Forget} N$ is the same as $\mathrm{Forget} \mathrm{Gr} M \cong \mathrm{Forget} N $ and then, as $\mathrm{Forget}$ is a functor and you know that $\mathrm{Gr} M\cong N$ you immediately get that $\mathrm{Forget} \mathrm{Gr} M \cong \mathrm{Forget} N $ holds and so $M\cong \mathrm{Forget} N$ .

Comment: if $R$ is semisimple you are done immediately as by splitting you essentially can decompose $M$ into the graded pieces as direct summands and then you are done straight forward. (this covers fields)

Comment: Well, proving that $M\cong Gr(M)$ as ungraded $R$-modules is precisely the tricky part. Do we know if this is true over  general commutative rings $R$ or at least over a field $k$?

Comment: for a field it is easy peasy, you got your morphisms into the quotients, take the sum of them, do dimension count and use that it is clearly surjective. Also works in more general semisimple cases. for general rings I am not sure. will think a little.

Comment: Does this proof work if we replace the $Gr_{\bullet}$ with respect to the direct sum with the more general associated graded defined as $\prod_{p\geq0}Gr_p$?

Comment: Do you assume that the vector space is finite dimensional? I do not want to assume that the vector space is finite dimensional.

Comment: And what do you mean by "you got your morphisms in the quotients". Which morphisms and which quotients? There are a few. And what is surjective? Wouldn't it be worthy to sum up your your posts in an answer?

Comment: What are you assuming about your filtration? The statement is false if $F_n M = F_{n-1} M$ for all $n$, or more generally if the filtration is not Hausdorff.

Comment: As for general commutative rings, you can filter $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ and get the same associated graded (two copies of $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are easy counterexamples for non-fields. If $R=\mathbb{Z}$, for example, then the filtration
$$
M = \mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z} \supseteq \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \supseteq 0
$$
has associated graded $\mathop{gr} M = \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, and $M \not \cong \mathop{gr} M$.

If $R$ is a field and if the filtration is Hausdorff (meaning that $\bigcap F_n M = 0$), then $\mathop{gr} M \cong M$ by dimension-counting. This is easy if $M$ is finite-dimensional, perhaps requires a bit more bookkeeping and care in the infinite-dimensional case.

If the filtration is not Hausdorff, then the claim can also fail. For example, the filtration
$$
M \supseteq M \supseteq M \supseteq M \supseteq \cdots
$$
(where all the inclusions are just equality) has associated graded $\mathop{gr} M = 0$. Similarly it can fail if you don't insist that $M = F_0 M$ (and I note that you do specify this): you need $\bigcup F_n M = M$ and $\bigcap F_n M = 0$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Does your proof can be extended from filtered vector spaces to modules $M$ over noetherian rings like the ring of formal power series in $n$ variables $R=\mathbb C[[t_1, ..., t_n]]$?

Comment: I think a similar counterexample to the case $R=\mathbb{Z}$ will work: the module $M = k[t_1]/(t_1^2)$ can be filtered by powers of $t_1$, and the associated graded will be $k \oplus k \not \cong M$.

Comment: $k\oplus k$ and $M$ are both $2$-dimensional $k$-vector spaces.  They are isomorphic over $k$, but you say that they are not isomorphic over $k[t_1]/(t_1)$. Do I understand you correctly?

Comment: When I wrote $k \oplus k$, to be completely explicit about the module structure, I perhaps should have written each $k$ instead as $k[t_1]/(t_1)$. So $k \oplus k$ and $M$ are not isomorphic over $k[t_1]$ or over $k[[t_1]]$. (They are isomorphic over $k[t_1]/(t_1)$, which itself is isomorphic as a ring to $k$.)

Comment: Does your proof survive if the filtration of the vector space $M$ is increasing and Hausdorff?

Comment: In general, you need $\bigcup F_n M = M$ and $\bigcap F_n M = 0$. I think that with these assumptions, dimension-counting should work fine.

Comment: So, it does not matter if the filtration is descending or ascending, right? The only two things that matter are that the filtration is exhaustive and Hausdorff?

Comment: @John Palmieri: The descending filtration on $k[[t]]$ is Hausdorff, but $gr k[[t]]=k[t]$?

Comment: @EricLey I think you're right, but that filtration is not exhaustive, is it?

Comment: It is automatically exhaustive since its descending?

Comment: Sure, sounds good.