# Isomorphism of associated graded of modules with increasing exhaustive filtrations induces an isomorphism of the modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, graded-modules, module-isomorphism, filtered-modules

Let $R$ be an ungraded commutative ring and let $M$ and $N$ be $R$- modules equipped with increasing and exhaustive filtrations, i.e $\{0\}\subset F_0P\subset\dots \subset F_nP\subset\dots\subset P$ such that $P=\cup_iF_iP$ for $P=M, N$. Let $f: M\to N$ be a morphism of filtered modules, i.e. $f(F_nM)\subseteq F_nN$ for every $n$ such that the induced map $\mathrm{Gr}(f): \mathrm{Gr}_{\bullet}(M)\to\mathrm{Gr}_{\bullet}(N)$ is an isomorphism of graded $R$-modules. Is it true that $f: M\to N$ is an isomorphism of filtered $R$-modules?

My opinion is the following: Based on the proof of the Lemma in the second answer to the question [Isomorphism of Associated Graded Algebras](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3043863/isomorphism-of-associated-graded-algebras/3048120#3048120), I believe that the exhaustiveness of the filtrations of $M$ and $N$ are enough to prove the above claim with the help of the Five Lemma.

**EDIT:** I added the specification "*isomorphism of graded $R$-modules*" instead of just "*isomorphism of $R$-modules*".

Comment: Yes, this is correct. By the five lemma, you can show that if $F_{i-1} M \rightarrow F_{i-1} N$ is an isomorphism, then $F_i M \rightarrow F_i N$ is one as well – by induction $f: F_i M \rightarrow F_i N$ is an isomorphism for all $i$. Then the kernel of $f$ has trivial intersection with any $F_i M$ so is trivial, while the image of $f$ contains every $F_i N$ so is $N$ – both claims hold because the filtrations are exhaustive.

Comment: Thank you, Aphelli! That is what I originally thought as well.  Does the argument in the induction proof go through if the ring $R$ is graded on its own?

Comment: Unfortunately, the above proof does not work for decreasing filtrations, does it?

Comment: If $R$ is graded, you may need to spell the definitions out again, but can’t you consider anyway the case $R=\mathbb{Z}$? For decreasing filtrations, I’m not sure, but what happens with the exact sequence $0 \rightarrow F^n(-)/F^{n+1}(-) \rightarrow (-)/F^{n+1}(-) \rightarrow (-)/F^n(-) \rightarrow 0$?

Comment: I think that when the ring $R$ is graded, as long as it has filtration degree zero, that is, it lies in $F_0M$ and in $F_0N$, nothing changes compared to the case of an ungraded ring $R$. If the generators of $R$ have a degree though, then, as you suggest, we should forget the ring $R$ and work with the underlying $\mathbb Z$-modules $M$ and $N$. Then, the same way as in your previous comment, we prove that $f:M\to N$ Is an isomorphism of  $\mathbb Z$-modules. But since $f$ is from the start an $R$-linear morphism, it follows that $f:M\to N$ is an isomorphism of $R$-modules. Do you agree?

Comment: As for the decreasing filtration, I am not sure if it is correct for any commutative base ring. Maybe it is correct for fields only.  Look for example at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4526481/isomorphism-of-associated-graded-vector-spaces-implies-an-isomorphism-of-vector?rq=1.

Comment: I agree with your first comment (“forgetting the $R$-structure” seems to work in every case to show that we have a bijective group homomorphism, since it is $R$-linear it is an isomorphism of $R$-modules). Not so much with your second comment, because it’s not the same setting in the question you linked (there, the isomorphism exists only abstractly for the graded pieces; here, it exists at the module level).

Comment: Yes, I agree with you about the decreasing filtration. That is a good point. Thank you.

Comment: Aphelli, According to Corollary $3$ on page $178$ in Bourbaki's "Commutative Algebra", the authors claim that a filtered morphism of filtered groups $u: X\to Y$ is bijective if the associated graded map $\mathrm{Gr(u)}$ is bijective, $X$ and $Y$ are Hausdorff, their filtrations are exhaustive and $X$ is complete. Any idea why they are assuming so many additional things apart from exhaustiveness? Is it possible that simple exhaustiveness does not suffice for the claim in my post? I do not see a mistake but I am alarmed by the additional assumptions that the authors make in the textbook.

Comment: I must specify that in Bourbaki, they assume at the very beginning of the chapter that for them all filtrations are decreasing, not increasing. This might be the reason why they need to assume bunch of additional conditions like Hausdorff'ness and completeness.

Comment: I don’t have Bourbaki at hand, but I don’t think increasing vs decreasing filtrations has any relevance whatsoever (if your index set is $\mathbb{Z}$, you can just reverse them!). Note that your filtrations are exhaustive by assumption, and Hausdorff by definition (since $F_{-1}=0$), so the only additional assumption is completeness. I think its point is to go from “finite” graded pieces (ie $F_p/F_q$) to the actual filtered pieces ($q \rightarrow -\infty$ to get $F_p$). It’s even possible that your filtrations are already complete for formal reasons (as their support is bounded below).

Comment: Thanks for your response. In Ben Dyer's answer in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3043863/isomorphism-of-associated-graded-algebras/3048120#3048120, he mentions that in case of a decreasing filtration, in order to prove subjectivity of the map, one needs to assume completeness of $X$. So, maybe the proofs for the increasing and decreasing  cases are not exactly the same.

Comment: In the hypothesis of increasing filtrations, I do not see the need of completeness of $X$. Ben Dyer claims that you need completeness of $X$ to prove surjectivity of the map $u: X\to Y$ when both filtrations are decreasing. I think you can still use the $5$ Lemma to prove that $F_iM\cong F_iN$ but you cannot simply take the colimit on both sides of the isomorphism because, I suspect, we do not have directed systems any longer.

Comment: Again, increasing vs decreasing is irrelevant here (because you can reindex with $F^i=F_{-i}$). You need completeness when *you can’t get to zero in finite time* – so *when your index set is $\mathbb{N}$*, this obviously only happens for infinite decreasing filtrations. The reason you then need completeness is that the “five lemma” only gives you isomorphisms $F^pX/F^q X \rightarrow F^p Y \rightarrow F^q Y$, but you need to manage to make $q \rightarrow \infty$ to relate this to $F^pX$… (note: we can always take the colimit of a system of isomorphisms…)

Comment: The five lemma gives us an isomorphisms between the first and the last two terms in $0\to F_{i-1}X\to F_{i}X\to\mathrm{Gr}_{i}(X)\to0$ and $0\to F_{i-1}Y\to F_{i}Y\to\mathrm{Gr}_{i}(Y)\to0$ from which we infer $F_iX\cong F_iY$ for all $i$. Where does this isomorphism $F^pX/F^qX\to F^pY\to F^qY$ come from? I do not see it?

Comment: So, if I understand you correctly, we do not need to assume completeness of $X$ in the case when the given filtrations are increasing or finite decreasing because we can reach zero in finite number of steps, correct? We only need completion in the case of infinite decreasing filtrations?